# Zuul, не настраивается маршрутизация

Tags: spring-boot, микросервисы, zuul

Пробую микросервисы и не получается заставить работать Zuul.
Сейчас у меня есть:
1) Сервис с конфигами
2) eureka
3) api с одним маршрутом /hello/user возвращающим строку
4) zuul
api и zuul регистрируются в eureka, но при попытке открыть страницу по адресу `api/v1/hello/user` получаю 404 и в консоли `No routes found from RouteLocator`

### Конфиг для Zuul

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=20000
ribbon.read-timeout=20000
ribbon.connect-timeout=20000
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false

zuul.ignored-services=*
zull.host.connect-timeout-millis=20000
zull.host.socket-timeout-millis=20000

zull.routes.api.path=/api/v1/**
zull.routes.api.service-id=api
zull.routes.api.stripPrefix=false

server.port=4000
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот конфиг с которым у меня все заработало:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeout-in-milliseconds=20000

ribbon.read-timeout=20000
ribbon.connect-timeout=20000

zuul.ignored-services='*'
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=20000
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=20000
zuul.routes.api.path=/api/v1/**
zuul.routes.api.service-id=api

server.port=4000
```